# PDF showing wrong character instead of Line feed

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

My application creates a PDF, but when the string the user wrote contains a line feed (\n) it shows the wrong character instead (in most fonts shows a little square)

When using [this](http://www.pdf-online.com/osa/validate.aspx) online validation tool it gives me the error

> The encoding for character code 10 in font 'Arial' is missing.

The "square character" began to appear when I started embedding fonts but using the same online validator in an older PDF (without embedded fonts) it gives me the same message.

[Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rpr5cny9vgozuar/Teste_SO_2.pdf?dl=0) to a PDF example.

PS: The error occurs in Acrobat, Foxit Reader and the Windows reader in Windows 8 but not in chrome.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The line feed characters themselves in the strings to show are the error.**

#### In detail

Your application creates page content streams with instructions like

```
1 0 0 1 15.1732 592.4547 Tm
(Test with line break
) Tj
1 0 0 1 15.1732 580.4547 Tm
(New Line.) Tj
```

In particular the string argument of the first **Tj** instruction contains a 0x0a byte before the closing bracket.

**Tj** is a text-showing operator. If you look into the PDF specification, you'll read that

> A string operand of a text-showing operator shall be interpreted as a sequence of character codes identifying the glyphs to be painted.

*(ISO 32000-1 section 9.4.3 Text-Showing Operators)*

I.e. each byte in such a string belongs to a byte sequence forming a character code to identify a glyph from the font.

In your case the font is defined as

```
<<
/Type /Font
/Subtype /TrueType
/BaseFont /Arial
/FirstChar 30
/LastChar 255
/Widths 4 0 R
/FontDescriptor 5 0 R
/Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding
>>
```

I.e. the encoding is **WinAnsiEncoding** which is defined in Annex D of ISO 32000-1. As you'll see there, there are no mappings for character codes below 040 = 0x20 = 32 defined for this encoding, in particular not for 0x0a, the character code you use.

Thus, the error message of the PDF validator is correct:

> The encoding for character code 10 in font 'Arial' is missing.

and the PDF viewers showing some "wrong character" (as you call it) merely try to make sense out of the invalid element 0x0a in the string argument of **Tj**.

Comment: Thank you so much! is there a workaround to make TrueType fonts with WinAnsiEncoding understand line breaks?

Comment: @Penachia What do you mean by *"understand line breaks"*? String arguments of text showing operators only identify glyphs. If you want 0x0a in such a string to represent a specific glyph, that is no problem, cf. section 9.6.6 *Character Encoding* of ISO 32000-1.But if you want a 0x0a to cause the text showing to jump to a next line, that is not possible because there is no control character interpretation of text showing arguments.

Comment: [in the PDF reference](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_archives/PDFReference.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A172%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C88%2C296%2Cnull%5D) (page 31) he uses \n to break lines I'd like to use that too, is there a way?

Comment: In other words, PDF does not know the concept of line breaks. You can only specify the location where you want to display glyphs. So, **you** have to handle newlines in your source text; simply stop displaying glyphs on the current line and start a new line below it. Do not include the new line character in the argument to **Tj**.

Comment: Thank you mkl for your time and patience and thanks @Brecht for the clarification.

Comment: @Penachia Concerning your PDF Reference link: Yes, a string in general can contain arbitrary contents including 0x0a bytes. But the meaning, the interpretation depends on the context in which the string is used. And the interpretation of string arguments of text showing operators is "sequence of character codes identifying glyphs". In other contexts, in particular outside of content streams, the interpretation differs. That been said, you do yourself no favor by using the non-normative PDF References, in particular such an old one. You had better switch to ISO 32000-1, even better ISO 32000-2.